# How to add String labels to both x and y axis in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add a String Label in order to label both the domain (x-axis) and the range (y-axis) of my `LineChart`, as shown in the picture below.
[image: a picture of a LineChart with "range" and "domain" labels outside the xAxis]

Any suggestions on how to do it using MPAndroidChart?

Comment: you either use additional TextViews outside the chart or modify the library to your purpose.

It's currently not supported by default

Answer (score 2):

*(Turning @Ironman's comment into an answer:)*

As of MPAndroidChart 3.0.1 this is currently not possible using the API exposed by the library. You will need to add additional `TextView` outside the chart, or modify the library to your purpose.

If you want to modify the library to your own purpose, you will need to study the source code [`XAxisRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/70691bea41a43d9df21db1a785ea3cec3f79c8fc/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/XAxisRenderer.java) and subclass it to add functionality to draw the axis label you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply this code

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true); //show y-axis at left
mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false); //hide y-axis at right


mChart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return "string_" + (int) value; // yVal is a string array
    }
});
```