# How to set label the for the x-axis?

Tags: mpandroidchart

How do I set the label for the `xAxis`? On the left side it currently has the label "amount". How do I add it programmatically?

[image: a chart with the xAxis label showing "amount"]

Comment: This question already has a community wiki answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656214/how-to-add-string-label-to-both-x-and-y-axis-in-mp-android-chart)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your preferences, you can use the data property of an Entry to store the label and then return it in your IAxisValueFormatter implementation:

```
public class LabelValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter { 

     private final DataSet mData;

public LabelValueFormatter(DataSet data) {
     mData = data;
} 

@Override 
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    // return the entry's data which represents the label 
    return (String) mData.getEntryForXPos(value, DataSet.Rounding.CLOSEST).getData();
 } 
}
```